# HttpContext null in Signalr OnConnected method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, signalr, signalr-hub

I am using signalr, but facing an issue in the `Onconnected` method. I need `urlreferrer` here but I get a null pointer exception.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    string urlreferrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(); 
    // Getting null exception here..
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where in the code is `base` given a value?

Answer (score 2):

SignalR exposes own `Context` object, which is bit different from `HttpContext`, but it contains most information about request.

To get referrer, you have to check http headers passed along with request. Like this:

```
public override Tasks.Task OnConnected()
{
    var referrer = Context.Request.Headers["Referer"];
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance that anybody is still searching for an answer to this, I've found that I was able to use an undocumented 'qs' parameter in the SignalR JS to pass data to the hub.  Using this method, it should be possible to get the referrer (on the client side) and send it to the server for further processing.

In the Client JS:

```
$.connection.hub.qs = "referrer=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href);
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    //initialization code
});
```

And in the server code:

```
   public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var str = Context.Request.QueryString["referrer"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

HTH!